# Pytorch mask missing values when calculating rmse

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to calculate the rmse error of two torch tensors. I would like to ignore/mask the rows where the labels are 0 (missing values). How could I modify this line to take that restriction into account?

```
torch.sqrt(((preds.detach() - labels) ** 2).mean()).item()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the shape of `preds` ?

Comment: It's of shape (batch_size=32, timestamps=12, nodes=207, features=2)

Comment: Use `print(preds.shape)` and paste it here.

Comment: I forgot about the number of batches.torch.Size([10, 32, 12, 207, 2])

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be solved by defining a custom MSE loss function* that masks out the missing values, 0 in your case, from both the input and target tensors:

```
def mse_loss_with_nans(input, target):

    # Missing data are nan's
    # mask = torch.isnan(target)

    # Missing data are 0's
    mask = target == 0

    out = (input[~mask]-target[~mask])**2
    loss = out.mean()

    return loss
```

(*) *Computing MSE is equivalent to RMSE from an optimisation point of view -- with the advantage of being computationally faster.*